# Interchanging derivative and integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm stuck with understanding the example from Lang "Undergraduate Analysis" that requires to prove that
$$
g(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(t)}{t}e^{-tx}dt \rightarrow g'(x)=-\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}\sin(t)dt
$$

The following theorem is supposed to be used: Assume that $f$ and $D_2f$ exist and are continuous. Assume that $\int_0^\infty D_2 f(t,x)dt$ converges uniformly for $x\in [c,d]$ and that $g(x)=\int_0^\infty f(t,x)dt$ converges $\forall x$. Then $g$ is differentiable and $g'(x)=\int_0^\infty D_2 f(t,x)dt$.

Could you please help me to understand:

1) Why the theorem is applicable here, especially how we may prove the uniform convergence in the example?

2) How the uniform convergence is related to the absolute convergence here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for $x \in [c,d]$ we have $|e^{-tx} \sin t| = e^{-tx} |\sin t| \leqslant e^{-tx} \leqslant e^{-ct}.$

Since the improper integral of $e^{-ct}$ over $[0,\infty)$ is convergent,  the improper integral of $e^{-tx} \sin t$ is absolutely and uniformly convergent by the Weierstrass test.

Thus, there exists a function $G$ for which we have uniform convergence as $n \to \infty$ of:

$$g_n'(x) = -\int_0^n e^{-tx} \sin t \, dt \to G(x).$$

Using a well-known theorem on uniform convergence and differentiability of sequences, this implies there is a function $g$ to which $g_n$ converges uniformly: 
$$g_n(x) = \int_0^n e^{-tx} \frac{\sin t}{t} \, dt \to g(x),$$

and where $g$ is differentiable with $g'(x) = G(x).$

Comment: Thank you for the reply! In your first inequality are we looking for an upper bound that doesn't depend on $x$? Will the reasoning be the same if the limits of integration are from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: @Konstantin:  The answer to your first question is yes -- that is how the Weierstrass test establishes uniform convergence. For the second question the integrals diverge with lower limit $-\infty$ since  $e^{-xt} \to +\infty$  as $t \to -\infty$ with $x >0.$.

Comment: One more question, if possible. Could you state the theorem on uniform convergence and differentiability of sequences that is applicable here?

Comment: In almost every real analysis book :  Suppose the sequence of differentiable functions $f_n:D \to \mathbb{R}$ converges pointwise for least one point $x_0 \in D$ and the sequence of derivatives $f_n'$ converges uniformly on $X$ to a function $g$.  Then there exists a function $f$ such that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $D$, $f$ is differentiable  and $f'(x) = g(x)$ for every $x \in D$.